# local variable 'direct1' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, django-views, global-variables

I am writing a simple program where I enter an employee ID number and it renders the data for that employee.  Here is my code on the backend:

```
def emp1(request):
import requests
import json

if request.method == 'POST':
    quote = request.POST['quote'] # or None

    if quote == "10001401":
        employee1 = requests.get("the api url")
        direct1 = json.loads(employee1.content)

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'quote': quote, 'direct1': direct1})
```

Now this works.  It's only when I enter another employee, that I am told that 'direct1' is referenced before assignment.  I tried to make the variable (direct1) global.  But I don't think I am grasping how to do that in django views.

Comment: Can quote not be "10001401"? If so, python tries to return `render(request, 'home.html', {'quote': quote, 'direct1': direct1})` without the direct1 actually being assigned/"created" beforehand.

Comment: I want quote which is what is posted on the frontend to render data based on a number  entered (10001401).  'direct1' is just me parsing the api data.  The program won't let me place it before the function.

Comment: what @J.Doe said is the error arise when quote is different than `"10001401"`. Just initialize the variable and probably you will solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, you can either return one indentation in or go with a direct1 = string() assignment (or whichever you need) in the beginning of your programme.

Comment: Thank you both.  What wound up working for me was to just make the variable direct1 global:

Comment: But I know that global variables are not really the best practice in the real world.